# QTableView / QTableWidget alternative for floats

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Writing a QGIS plugin with PyQGIS I need a table to store and view values that are floats. I found only these two models (QTableView / QTableWidget), but they only store QString type of data, and therefore sorting of numbers gets wrong (eg. `10, 23512, 24, 35, 6874` would be correct order while it's obviously not). 
Main problems that I have are:

- Proper sorting is very important
- Size of values stored can be any (eg. can't say it will be always 4 digits with 2 precision digits)

Is there any alternative to store numbers in tables in QGIS plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you must create a new widget derived from the QTable, and set these constraits manually.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25539830/3416863) is an example how to sort columns:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class QCustomTableWidgetItem (QtGui.QTableWidgetItem):
    def __init__ (self, value):
        super(QCustomTableWidgetItem, self).__init__(QtCore.QString('%s' % value))

    def __lt__ (self, other):
        if (isinstance(other, QCustomTableWidgetItem)):
            selfDataValue  = float(self.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString())
            otherDataValue = float(other.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString())
            return selfDataValue < otherDataValue
        else:
            return QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.__lt__(self, other)

class QCustomTableWidget (QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.setRowCount(5)
        for row in range(self.rowCount()):
            self.setItem(row, 0, QCustomTableWidgetItem(random.random() * 1e4))
            self.setItem(row, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(QtCore.QString(65 + row)))
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)
```

If you want to set decimal precision you must do this in similar way.

Comment: this worked very well, thank you! but it appeared I only needed the `QCustomTableWidgetItem` class, the other one wasn't neccessary as I'm adding these custom `...Item`s to a regular table and don't have to delcare new one anywhere.